# Java Web integrated with Bing Speech API

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, bing-api, microsoft-speech-api

I am developing an application using Java Web with JSF and would like to integrate Speech API using JavaScript.

What I did was insert the 'speech.1.0.0.js' file in my application and used the 'index.html' to test (informed the key and SubscriptionId), but nothing happens. I forgot to do something?

This is the page's source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-start" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/estilo.css.jsf?ln=css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3"></script><script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.projectStage='Development';}</script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Web RAF - LABI</title>
    <style type="text/css">
<!--
#logotipo {
    text-align: center;
}
-->
</style></head><body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logotipo">
            <!-- &lt;h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="logotipo_g.png" /&gt; -->
        </div>
        <div id="barra_menu">
    <!-- Menu  -->
<form id="j_idt12" name="j_idt12" method="post" action="/webraf/restrito/laudo_teste.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt12" value="j_idt12" />

            <div id="menu"><span id="j_idt12:messages"></span><script id="j_idt12:messages_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_j_idt12_messages',{id:'j_idt12:messages',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:[]});});</script><div id="j_idt12:j_idt14" class="ui-menu ui-menubar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" role="menubar"><div tabindex="0" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div><ul class="ui-menu-list ui-helper-reset"><li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="#" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-submenu-link ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">LAUDO MÉDICO</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a><ul class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-list ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-menu-child ui-shadow" role="menu"><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="/webraf/restrito/laudo.jsf"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Gerar</span></a></li><li class="ui-separator ui-state-default"></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="/webraf/restrito/laudo_editar.jsf"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Editar</span></a></li><li class="ui-separator ui-state-default"></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="/webraf/restrito/laudo_teste.jsf"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Gerar Laudo (Teste)</span></a></li><li class="ui-separator ui-state-default"></li></ul></li><li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="#" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-submenu-link ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">CADASTRAR</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a><ul class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-list ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-menu-child ui-shadow" role="menu"><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="/webraf/restrito/profissional.jsf"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Profissional</span></a></li><li class="ui-separator ui-state-default"></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="/webraf/restrito/paciente.jsf"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Paciente</span></a></li></ul></li><li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="#" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-submenu-link ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">CONFIGURAR</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a><ul class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-list ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-menu-child ui-shadow" role="menu"><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">SRAF</span></a></li></ul></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-menubar-options ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                        <!-- &lt;p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" placeholder="Search"/&gt; -->
                        <!-- Administrador -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script>
<a href="#" title="Administrativo" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt12'),{'j_idt12:j_idt29':'j_idt12:j_idt29'},'');return false"><img src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/administrativo.png.jsf?ln=imagens" /></a>
                        <!-- Principal --><a href="#" title="Principal" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt12'),{'j_idt12:j_idt32':'j_idt12:j_idt32'},'');return false"><img src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/principal.png.jsf?ln=imagens" /></a>
                        <!-- Sair -->
                        <a onclick="document.location='/webraf/j_spring_security_logout'" title="Sair"><img src="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/logout.png.jsf?ln=imagens" />
                        </a></li></ul></div><script id="j_idt12:j_idt14_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("Menubar","widget_j_idt12_j_idt14",{id:"j_idt12:j_idt14",autoDisplay:true});</script>
            </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-3017596759583924659:90283694441848566" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
        </div>
        <div id="corpo"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webraf/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-start" /><script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.projectStage='Development';}</script>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />           
            <script src="/resources/js/speech.1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        var client;
        var request;

        function useMic() {
            return document.getElementById("useMic").checked;
        }

        function getMode() {
            switch (document.getElementById("mode").value) {
                case "longDictation":
                    return Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionMode.longDictation;
                default:
                    return Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionMode.shortPhrase;
            }
        }

        function getOxfordKey() {
            return document.getElementById("oxfordkey").value;
        }

        function getLanguage() {
            return "en-us";
        }

        function clearText() {
            document.getElementById("output").value = "";
        }

        function setText(text) {
            document.getElementById("output").value += text;
        }

        function getLuisConfig() {
            var appid = document.getElementById("luis_appid").value;
            var subid = document.getElementById("luis_subid").value;

            if (appid.length > 0 <![CDATA[&&]]> subid.length > 0) {
                return { appid: appid, subid: subid };
            }

            return null;
        }

        function start() {
            var mode = getMode();
            var luisCfg = getLuisConfig();

            clearText();

            if (useMic()) {
                if (luisCfg) {
                    client = Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClientWithIntent(
                        getLanguage(),
                        getOxfordKey(),
                        getOxfordKey(),
                        luisCfg.appid,
                        luisCfg.subid);
                } else {
                    client = Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(
                        mode,
                        getLanguage(),
                        getOxfordKey(),
                        getOxfordKey());
                }
                client.startMicAndRecognition();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    client.endMicAndRecognition();
                }, 5000);
            } else {
                if (luisCfg) {
                    client = Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createDataClientWithIntent(
                        getLanguage(),
                        getOxfordKey(),
                        getOxfordKey(),
                        luisCfg.appid,
                        luisCfg.subid);
                } else {
                    client = Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createDataClient(
                        mode,
                        getLanguage(),
                        getOxfordKey(),
                        getOxfordKey());
                }
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open(
                    'GET',
                    (mode == Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionMode.shortPhrase) ? "whatstheweatherlike.wav" : "batman.wav",
                    true);
                request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                request.onload = function () {
                    if (request.status !== 200) {
                        setText("unable to receive audio file");
                    } else {
                        client.sendAudio(request.response, request.response.length);
                    }
                };

                request.send();
            }

            client.onPartialResponseReceived = function (response) {
                setText(response);
            }

            client.onFinalResponseReceived = function (response) {
                setText(JSON.stringify(response));
            }

            client.onIntentReceived = function (response) {
                setText(response);
            };
        }       
    </script></head>
        <div align="right">Bem-vindo, thiago</div>

            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><h1>Speech.JS</h1>
                        <h2>Microsoft Cognitive Services</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"></td>
                    <td><input id="useMic" type="checkbox" />Use Microphone</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Mode:</td>
                    <td><select id="mode">
                            <option selected="selected">shortPhrase</option>
                            <option>longDictation</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><A href="https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/sign-up" target="_blank">Subscription</A>:</td>
                    <td><input id="oxfordkey" type="text" size="40" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">LUIS AppId:</td>
                    <td><input id="luis_appid" type="text" size="40" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">LUIS SubscriptionId:</td>
                    <td><input id="luis_subid" type="text" size="40" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button onclick="start()">Start</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><textarea id="output" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
    </div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more precise on what do you mean "nothing happens". Did you load the page in browser or what? What there something in javascript console log?

Comment: Nikolay, that is the problem. There is generated no message of any kind on the console.

Select the option to capture speech by the microphone and when I click the 'Start' button, my speech is not converted to text. The button 'Start' invoke a JavaScript tmethod to start capturing speech and convert to text

Comment: Does the demo here https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api work for you? What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi, Nikolay. Segui todos os passos da documentação. 

Testei no Chrome e no IE 11 e Edge.

Comment: I asked if dictation on the page works for you

Comment: The dictation on page does not work for me.

Comment: What happens when you try dictation on microsoft page

Comment: I'm sorry, Nikolay. I did not understand your question.

My test in the Microsoft page (https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api) works, as appears the transcript of what I speak. What does not appear transcription, it is my application when invoke the JavaScript Bing Speech.

Comment: Ok, provide the source of the page you see in browser

Comment: I put the page's source code in question body.

Comment: Does it work without the microphone check?

Comment: Everything is ok with the microphone. Works for Microsoft's test page.

Comment: I ask if your own page works with the file, not with the microphone.

Comment: Hello. My page does not work with the test files 'whatstheweatherlike' and 'Batman'.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What exactly happens?

Comment: "Does not work" want to say I put the audio file on my page and when I click the button 'start' the page does not invoke Bing Speech to transcribe the audio file. Note: when I click the 'start' button, the page does not transcribes the audio file into text and the application does not generate any error message. It's like not invoke the JavaScript or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adjusting the import in javascript because I utlizando JSF

```
<h:outputScript target="head" library="js" name="speech.1.0.0.js" />
<h:outputScript target="head" library="js" name="microsoft.js" />
```